# Compact injection of $W^{1,p}(I)$ into $L^\infty(I)$ for bounded $I$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Brezis says that for a bounded open interval $I$, the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^\infty(I)$ is continuous for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset C(\bar{I})$ is compact for $1 < p \leq \infty$.

Does this imply the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^\infty(I)$ is also compact? The two issues are that the first compact injection is into $C(\bar{I})$, not $C(I)$, and that the injection is not into $L^\infty(I)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the values of a continuous function on an open set determine the values on the closure, restriction to $I$ provides a natural injection $C(\bar I) \hookrightarrow L^\infty (I)$. Since we use the sup norm for both spaces, this map is continuous. Composing it with the compact embedding $W^{1,p} \hookrightarrow C(\bar I)$ gives a compact embedding $W^{1,p} \hookrightarrow L^\infty (I)$.

Comment: beginner's question: how does it make sense that $C(\bar I) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(I)$ where in $L^\infty(I)$ functions don't have to be defined on the boundary of $I$ ?

Comment: @cesareborgia: an injection/embedding doesn't necessarily have to be an obvious inclusion. In this case the injection takes a function in $C(\bar I)$ and restricts it to $I$. This is injective because if $f \in C(\bar I)$, then we can recover $f$ from $f|_I \in L^\infty(I)$ by taking limits at the endpoints.

Comment: thanks a lot, that totally makes sense :-)